# Error in gvisLineChart while I have a data frame

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot some numbers of a data frame using `gvisLineChart`. The data I am feeding is a data.frame but still I am getting the error that `Error: data has to be a data.frame`.

My data has one single column, I trimmed the zeros & want to plot the remaining numbers.

My data frame is like below;

```
mydf$figures
 [1] 1250  760 2590 7990 2070 6770 4760 4270 2550 6070 4580 2350 1510 4140 2450 3010 1070 1230  850  490  170 1970    0    0
[25]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Then I trimmed the zeros;

```
mydf2<- subset(mydf,figures != 0)
mydf2$figures
[1] 1250  760 2590 7990 2070 6770 4760 4270 2550 6070 4580 2350 1510 4140 2450 3010 1070 1230  850  490  170 1970
```

Now I want to plot the numbers;

```
library(googleVis)
library(googleCharts)
gvisLineChart(mydf2$figures)
Error in gvisCoreChart(data, xvar, yvar, options, chartid, chart.type = "LineChart") : 
  Error: data has to be a data.frame.
```

But, when I am checking the class, it is `data.frame`

```
class(mydf2)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Please help me to understand the error properly & guide me how can I plot the numbers using `gvisLineChart`. TIA

Comment: Sure, but `class(mydf2$figures)` is not a data frame, you know?

Comment: Yes, I just checked. It's ```numeric```. Then I thought I need to only pass the data. It's still giving error though. Do I need to specify ```xvar``` & ```yvar``` seperately?
```
gvisLineChart(mydf2)
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , c(xvar, yvar)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure, don't know the function, though. Check the documentation with `?gvisLineChart`, there should be an example included to see how they pass the data.

Comment: Still getting error, this time it's different though.

```
gvisLineChart(mydf2,xvar=index, yvar="figures")
Error in xvar == "" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```